# Compute the pdf $p(y) = \int_{CP^{N-1}} \delta \left( \frac{1-\bar \xi_{N-1} \xi_{N-1}}{1+ \xi^\dagger \xi} - y\right)d\mu_{CP^{N-1}} (\xi,\bar\xi)$

Tags: probability-distributions, complex-geometry

I am trying to determine the pdf of $Y = \langle{\psi}|Z^{\otimes n}|\psi\rangle$ when $|\psi\rangle$ is sampled randomly wrt the Haar measure. Let $\xi = [\xi_1, \dots,\xi_{N-1}]^T \in \mathbb{C}^{N-1}, (N = 2^n)$ and [represent](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9013/7648)
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{[1, \xi_1, \dots, \xi_{N-1}]^T}{1+\xi^\dagger \xi}$$
with the Fubini Study measure
$$ d\mu_{CP^{N-1}} (\xi,\bar\xi) = \frac{(N-1)!}{\pi^{N-1}} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} d\xi_k d\bar\xi_k}{(1+\xi^\dagger \xi)^N}$$

The pdf is $$p(y) = \int_{CP^{N-1}} \delta \left( \frac{1-\bar \xi_{N-1} \xi_{N-1}}{1+ \xi^\dagger \xi} - y\right)d\mu_{CP^{N-1}} (\xi,\bar\xi)$$

Is there any elementary way to evaluate the integral?